# How to detect stuff that has not been released properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Writing a program for the iphone. Realized that I forgot to release an object, but there was really no indication that the object was not released everything just worked.

What is the best way to track something like this down?  Is there a way to see what objects still exist in memory when the program exits out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [Leaks tool in Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html).

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, when the program exits, it doesn’t matter what you’ve left in memory: the system frees everything that your application allocated throughout its lifetime. Since iOS 4, though, apps usually just get frozen in the background and don’t exit until the system kills them to free up memory. To avoid that—and to reduce your app’s memory footprint, which is important while it’s running—you should, as highlycaffeinated and Daniel suggested, use Instruments’s Leaks tool to check for objects that aren’t getting deallocated properly.

Answer (score 5):

When the app exits, anything in memory is destroyed by the system (not deallocated-- but just outright destroyed when the address space is given back to the system).

While others have suggested using the Leaks tool to find leaks in your app, Leaks won't find many many kinds of memory accretion.  If an object is allocated, shoved in a cache somewhere, then the key to that object in the cache is lost, the object is effectively leaked (can never be used again) but won't be find by Leaks because it is still connected to your viable object graph.

A better bet is to use Heapshot analysis to see how your app's object graph grows over time.  I wrote up a [tutorial on using Heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) that you might find useful.

If you want to grab a snapshot just before your app exits, then put a `sleep(1000);` into your code in either an application termination handler or somewhere else that is executed just before the app exits.

Just remember to remove it before shipping a production build. :)

Answer (score 3):

Once an application quits - you don't have access to that. But Instruments (an XCode tool) can look for memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing exists in memory when pprogram exits. But you can start with analyzing your code (Product -> Analyze) and running it with (Product -> Profile) Allocations or Leaks in Instruments to find memory management issues.

Comment: This is my preferred method for finding obvious leaks, but it doesn't work so well for hidden "not-obvious" leaks.